# Django: CreateView with additional field?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to program a Django CreateView (CBV), which takes instead of the user id the user email and determines (or creates) the user based on the email.

My model does not contain anything special:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100,)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'),)
    ...
```

My forms.py adds the additional email field to the form:

```
class ProjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', ...,)
```

In my views.py, I am trying to determine if the user exists or should be created. In both cases, the user id should be saved as part of the Project instance.

```
class ProjectCreateDetails(CreateView):
    form_class = ProjectCreateForm
    template_name = '...'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login') 
    model = Project

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=form.email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_user(form.email, form.email, ''.join([random.choice(string.digits + string.letters) for i in range(0, 10)]))
            user.save()
        form.instance.user = user
        return super(ProjectCreateDetails, self).form_valid(form)
```

**However I am facing an error that the `'Solution' object has no attribute 'email'`.**

Do I need to switch to a FormView instead of a CreateView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the error `'Solution' object has no attribute 'email'` because `form.email` is invalid. Validated data is never available as attributes of a form or model form. When forms (including model forms) are valid, the successfully validated data is available in the [`form.cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form) dictionary.

Note that you don't need to call `user.save()`. The `create_user` call has already added the user to the database. You don't have to generate a random password either -- if `password` is `None`, then [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) will set an unusable password.

Finally, make sure that you do not include the `user` field in the `ProjectCreateForm`. You probably do not, but your code says `fields = ('name', ...,)` so I can't tell for sure.

Put it together and you get the following (untested) code:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['email']) 
    form.instance.user = user
    return super(ProjectCreateDetails, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Just writing this comment to point out that you can use get_or_create method

Comment: @AymaneShuichi No, we can't use `get_or_create` here - we are using the `create_user` method so that the password is handled correctly.