# Modify createView so as to post to two different forms from same template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models which have common fields, say

```
class model1(models.Model):
    commonfield1 = ...
    commonfield2 = ...

class model2(models.Model):
    commonfield1 = ...
    commonfield2 = ...
    extrafields=..
    ....
```

Now I have two different create forms for these both models using `forms.ModelForm`
Now, my requirement is that when I create a new object for **model2**, I also want to save an object in **model1**.

As of now, I am using CreateView to save the form for **model2**.
I want to give the user an option such that if he presses that save two objects button both the models should be updated accordingly.

Is there any way I can do this using `CreateView`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a duplicate question, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420306/django-createview-with-additional-field) should help you out.

In order to do this, you need to first add a field to your modelForm, and second, overwrite form_valid. If your custom field is checked, then you should manually call `model2.objects.create(...)` with the proper fields from the form.

Comment: I have many to many common field in the form, I am not able to use object.create because of this reason.

Comment: Well either way, you're going to have to overwrite your view's form_valid method (thats the function called when the form is processed). Just use the values from the form to manually do the parts that createView won't